# Подскажите как правильно сделать переход Login in c DrawerMenu?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, android-navigation-drawer

У меня Login in c Firebase Auth, не понял как сделать переход в Меню (меню у меня с функцией "Is initial View Controller" или проще говоря "Slide Menu (Drawer)". Как сделать чтоб сначала загружалась регистрация, а потом при правильном входу появлялось меню. Если можно ссылкой на пример.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У вас слишком обширный вопрос, который заключается в том чтобы показать вам код как все сделать.

Советую делать пошагово и разбить задачу вашу на подзадачи:

1. Сделать чтобы первый экран была регистрация
2. Сделать регистрацию
3. Проверять успешна ли она
4. и тд ...

Начать можете с 1ого: на экране логин нажми `is initial view controller` и он будет открываться первым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS> советую вам искать вопросы так же пошагово а не раскрыто по типу "как сделать логин и переход в меню". Декомпозируйте свою задачу :)

Comment: Ну знаешь это я знаю и разобрался.